# Parse image overwrite with same name

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using Parse.File() in cloud code for storing the thumbnail(JPEG),So once user edits profile with new profile image I create a thumbnail with new Parse.File() and saves the data.
Now the case is each new Parse File object creates the new file and uploads on server creating a new file "NAME" in the database which is correct.

But my requirement is that I want to keep the name of the thumbnail same.
i.e
If current name is 1.JPEG then after uploading the image name should remain 1.JPEG.
and if the user is uploading the image first time then it will generate the unique value as per parse File object behavior.

Any updates on this would be very helpful.  :)

Comment: Share what you have so that we can see what you tried.

Comment: @Snake Blisken Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: parseObject.get("originalImageColumn").url();}).then(function(response) { return image.setData(response.buffer); }).then(function(image) { var tmp = image.scale({ width: 50, height: 50 }); tmp.setFormat('JPEG'); tmp.data(); return tmp; }).then(function(buffer) {var base64 = buffer.toString('base64'); var file = new Parse.File('image.jpg', { base64: base64 }); return file.save(); }).then(function(file) { return parseObject.set(thumbnailColumn, file); });
I want to use same file name for thumbnail if present in DB.